# CSS: Maintain Aspect Ration of Div Element

Tags: css, html

I tried to solve my problem searching through the various questions already posted, but I have not found one that is made for my

I'm creating my new website using the "responsive" technique and now I'm missing just one little thing:

I enter inside a DIV a background image
The DIV should have a width of 100% to fill the entire page, and I have to make sure that the height of the DIV that contains the image will auto resize when resizing the page.

Comment: Please post your code that you have already.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking.  Please try to explain a little better what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the image to retain the width and height of the containing div, use:

```
background-size: 100% 100%;
```

The image will distort, but you may not mind.

If you want the background to be whatever portion of the image is sufficient to cover the 
entire div as the viewport changes, use:

```
background-size: cover;
```

If you want to ensure that the entire image is in the background with the proper aspect ratio, use:

```
background-size: contain;
```

In this case, the image may be tiled to cover the div.

HTML

```
<div id="thediv"></div>
```

CSS

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

#thediv {
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/MabCTXH.jpg);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

Comment: Meanwhile, thanks for the reply,
But there is a little problem

with this code

<style>
# {thediv
height: 100%;
background-image: url (T.png);
background-size: 100% 100%;
}
</ style>


<div id="thediv"> </ div>

the div with the background image takes up the whole page in length (width), but I would not occupy the whole in height.

I would like to occupy the whole page in width, but the height will auto resize when the page is resized

I hope I explained

thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for? I just added the `padding: 5px;` and `background-color: red;` so op can see that the div is 100% wide and is responsive as well as the image
http://jsfiddle.net/hyKCa/1/

Comment: I don't think that's what he wants. It looks like he's setting an image using the css `background` property. Until code is posted we shall not know.